# SumoLogic RESTFul API C# client

Tags: rest, sumologic

Is there any C# client anyone know about that we can use to run queries against SumoLogic?  I see they have a [Java Client](https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumo-java-client) but cannot find a corresponding C# client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SumoLogicMessageSender](https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumologic-net-appenders/blob/master/SumoLogic.Logging.Common/Sender/SumoLogicMessageSender.cs) class. 
You can find using this class [here](https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumologic-net-appenders/blob/master/SumoLogic.Logging.Log4Net/SumoLogicAppender.cs).

But, I don't recommend to use GetResult() like it writes in original code :

```
// this maintains synchronous behavior for single event scenarios.
        this.SumoLogicMessageSender
            .TrySend(bodyBuilder.ToString(), this.SourceName, this.SourceCategory, this.SourceHost)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
```